# Maximum number of fixed points in a permutation

Tags: permutations, fixed-points

What is the maximum number of fixed points of a permutation $\sigma$ from $S_{12}$, if the subgroup generated by $\sigma$ in the group ($S_{12}$, composition of permutations ($\circ$) ) has $12$ elements?

Comment: What did you try? What are the possible group(s) of size $12$ generated by a single element?